# regex to get exception after last match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex in javascript to search for hex code in a string

```
const regex = /([a-f0-9]{8})/g
```

which works fine, but of course it doesn't get the last piece of the hex code because it is shorter, in my case it is `732e`. How could I approach it to have a look for exception on the last row? The last row and next-to-last row look like this. I want to avoid loosing the rules, because I am affraid to match something that is not hex code

```
45270a70 36313837 0a615327 756e6930
34324627 0a703631 38380a61 732e
```

It is a binary file, that gets converted to hex code, then it gets translated to ASCII and in that ASCII is hex code which I need to match. I did that, except the last exception. So it is hex code among rubbish and strings.

thanks!

Comment: Use `s.match(/\b[a-f0-9]{1,8}\b/g)`, or in your case, you can even split a string with whitespace, `s.split(/\s+/)`.

Comment: If the value is inside a long messy text, try `/\b[a-f0-9]{8}(?:\s+[a-f0-9]{8})*(?:\s+[a-f0-9]{4})?\b/g`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/loFxY9/1).

Comment: Note you will be able to split the result of the above regex match with `.split(/\s+/)`. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
/\b[a-f0-9]{4}(?:[a-f0-9]{4}\b|[a-f0-9]{0,4}$)/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xXf3C6/2)

This will allow exception for last string in a line only to match 4-8 hex digits. For all other cases it must match 8 hex digits only.

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[a-f0-9]{4}`: Match 4 hex digits
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[a-f0-9]{4}`: Match 4 hex digits
  - `\b`: Assert word boundary
  - `|`: OR
  - `[a-f0-9]{0,4}`: Match 0 to 4 hex digits
  - `$`: End
- `)`: End non-capture group

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
const regex = /([a-f0-9]{1,8})/g
```

`{1,8}` matches the exceptions which are less than 8 characters and also valid strings.

**Note:** Of course this is the answer to your question if the exceptions don't follow specific rules such as string length.

**Update:**

https://regex101.com/r/QgMfyr/1

Comment: No, because it matches nearly the whole file

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why that works, to help others who find this question and answer.